# ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation - on replace fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-animation

Is there a way to create a similar animation to ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(View source, int startX, int startY, int startWidth, int startHeight) on replace fragment transaction? When a user clicks on a editTextBox I need to scale up from the editTextBox to a fullscreen fragment.